# How can you lazy load typescript file (only file not module) in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

let's say we have different config files for a module, we want to dynamically import a config file based on flag, how can we achieve same in angular?

lazy laod a module and only particular config should be downloaded. let's say we have feature A and feature B both share a common module which is lazy loaded (Module M) , we have different config placed inside Module M feature A (featureA.config) and feature B (featureB.config), We want to lazy load the config with subsequent module.